# React App just shows the starting page on Github pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, github-pages

I create a react app, that has multiple routes, which works correctly on localhost. But when I deploy it on github pages using `npm run deploy` only the homepage is shown.

Details : The app is named, cp-tools. When I open `username.github.io/cp-tools/` I get the homepage as expected, but when I open say,`username.github.io/cp-tools/problem-filter/`or any other page github says, 404 page not found.

`Routing (App.js):`

```
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <BrowserRouter basename ={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path = '/' component = {Home} /> 
          <Route exact path = '/problem-filter' component = {ProblemFilter} /> 
          <Route path = '*' component = {NotFound} /> 
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
```

`package.json :`

```
{
"homepage": "https://pshishod2645.github.io/cp-tools",
// other details
}
```

Comment: <Route exact path = '/problem-filter' component = {ProblemFilter} />  remove exact keyword from this line and then you rebuild the application. it will work

Answer (score 0):

The way GitHub pages works is that, request to an URL `username.github.io/cp-tools`, will be served by the `index.html` file found in the `github.com/username/cp-tools` repository, IF the repository has gh-pages setup.

If you go to `username.github.io/cp-tools/problem-filter` on your browser, GitHub will fail to find any files matching that path, thus showing 404 errors. You can still navigate to that page from the entrypoint via client-side routing (using `react-router-dom` `<Link />`, `history.push()`, etc).

I would suggest looking into other static hosting service such as [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) and [Zeit Now](https://zeit.co/) for this requirement.

But, if you want to stay with GH pages, a workaround is to use `hashHistory` instead, which uses the `#` for defining path for your React app. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765#issuecomment-285114194).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an exact path for `/` home component only. If you put exact keyword for all router component its takes first component.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

follow below line code :
 **Routing (App.js):**

```
 <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <BrowserRouter basename ={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path = '/' component = {Home} /> 
          <Route path = '/problem-filter' component = {ProblemFilter} /> 
          <Route path = '*' component = {NotFound} /> 
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
```